# STM32cubeMX Firmware Package

Tags: stm32, stm32f4discovery, stm32ldiscovery, stm32f4, stm32l152

I start generate code in STM32cubeMX, and i got this message "The Firmware Package(STM32Cube FW_F4 V1.11.0)or one of its dependencies requiredby the Project is not available in your STM32CubeMX Repository". Can enyone  tell me how to throw in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This message indicates that the necessary firmware (for STM32F4 family) not installed. Under GNU/Linux with the newest CubeMX a possibility appears with this message enables install the appropriate firmware. If it is not your case first upgrade your CubeMX and after you need install the additional software (in your case STM32CubeF4) for your microcontroller. You can install it form the CubeMX Help/Install New Libraries.

You can read more detailed information from the [STM32CubeMX](http://www.st.com/stm32cube) homepage and under the STM32CubeF4 link on the page.